# Dynamic Frequency Evaluation on Massive Random Numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I use a random function(Let's call it `randomNum`()) to generate random numbers(unsigned long) continuously(will generate about one million numbers in total).My question is How to determine whether the frequency of current number generated is greater than 20%(among the total numbers generated so far) efficiently?

Please write down your opinion or your c code?Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual range of the random numbers?

Answer (score 2):

A hash-table, whose entries are the count for each value?

Comment: The problem is that 1 million is muuch smaller than the range of unsigned long, so if the `randomNum()` is OK (have homogenous distribution), there will be nothing to count actually.

Comment: The OP means a hash with one million elements; you can only have a maximum of one million different numbers.

Comment: I know, and gave him +1. The commentary was for schemacs.

Comment: My classmate first thought about balanced-search-tree.But the requirement for memory(hash-table and balanced-search-tree) is huge,is this right?

Comment: @schemacs: The storage requirement will be proportional to the number of different values that have been drawn.  You can't really get around the fact that potentially (and extremely likely in practice), each value drawn could be different, so you need to set up a counter for each one.

Comment: Yes,each value draw may be different.Do you mean that I have to set up counters for each number generated?The memory usage will skyrocket on massive random numbers.

Comment: @schemacs: Of course!  But 1 million is a lot less than 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you are asking:

> If I draw 10^6 samples from an RNG
>   which can produce any integer in the
>   range 0..(2^32)-1 what is the
>   probability that 0.2 x 10^6 of the
>   samples will have the same value ?

Unless your RNG is seriously flawed the answer is 0 probability, to more decimal places than you ought to worry about in any realistic set of circumstances.

So, obviously, I have misunderstood the question ...

Comment: Oh,You misunderstood the question.Focus on DYNAMIC.That means you have TO determinate each number's frequency you just draw from the RNG(the total numbers are the numbers you have draw in total till now).

Comment: @schemacs: In the situation you describe, the "frequency" of each value will be 0 or 1, with high probability.

Comment: You mean the frequency is 0 or 1 for each value?The frequency is range in [0,1] here,which equals to n(cur_val)/n(total_till_now). n(cur_val) is the number of appearance time for current value,and n(total_till_now) is the total number.